# My Laravel display main page but the rest not found in nginx server using aapanel

Tags: laravel, mod-rewrite, routes, config

I have Laravel 6 running well on my localhost but when I deploy on domainsite.com, it only shows the main page but the rest of links shows 404 page not found. I am using CentOS 7, aaPanel running nginx server. PHP 7.4 MySQL.
I have this config so far.

URL Rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

fileinfo installed

I have removed in Disabled Functions(putenv and symlink) but still I get the error.
Anyone have tried this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please do mention in your question what error are you getting, thank you.

Comment: "404 Not Found" then below "nginx"

Comment: Could you please do let me know if your htaccess and index.php are present in same path?

Comment: Yes it is on the same folder... public folder of laravel.

Comment: i just tried included domainsite.com/index.php/about

Comment: but with these -> domainsite.com/about ,-- not working

Comment: Kindly do post exact path of your htaccess and index.php once? Also what sample link you are hitting and getting error.

Comment: i have htaccess on main folder of laravel and htaccess and index.php on /public folder.

Comment: Can you find any hints if this might be due to SELinux?
`setenforce 0` and retry (remember to revert to setenforce 1 again after testing).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It doesn't work.. I have reverted.

Comment: Can you try running `ls -aZ` in the folder that works and also the folder that doesn't work and see whether there's any difference in the context? The goal here is to set the context to be the same with `chcon` command.

Comment: I see the list of files and its permission